# Preventing an ntfs partition from ever mounting

Tags: usb, raspbmc

**Question**

How do I BANISH NTFS FOREVER from raspbmc?

**Background**

I don't know what's the problem between my raspbmc and my external hdd. All I know is that the ntfs partition of the external hdd keeps "removing" and "connecting succesfully" in an infinite loop. The ext4 partition (the one that matters) works just fine. The problem is that if this loop is not interrupted, the pi eventually crashes and I have to reset (unplug and replug the cord). *Even* if I `sudo umount /media/ntfsshit` through ssh, raspbmc remounts it again! Against my will!

I tried removing the ntfs-3g package (didn't work). Then I added a blacklist.conf file to `/etc/modprobed.d` and it didn't work. It was like this:

```
blacklist ntfs
# the above didn't solve the problem, so I added:
install ntfs /bin/false
# but didn't work either
```

I'm tearing my hair off of my head, and I keep looking at my hammer, then to the pi, then to my hammer, and the idea of smashing it seems more and more attractive.

Please, save a stranger's sanity. Thanks a bunch!

**MORE DETAILS**:

The pi is connected to a wall outlet through a cellphone charger and the two usb ports are used as follows:

> lower port: 7-ports powered usb hub (with a wireless mouse and the hdd)
>
> upper: DWA-131 wireless dongle

Comment: Smashing your pi!??! GASP!! :D Just kidding, I know what you meant. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, folks. The problem had not much to do with ntfs itself, but with the power delivered to the external hdd. The powered usb hub I was using delivered around 500 mA. I replaced it with a 3.8A usb hub, which is effectively 7 x 500mA + some extra juice for the hub itself, I suppose. The thing is that the usb specification requires each port to be able to deliver 500mA, so this new hub is able to deliver that amount (and more) of energy through each of its 7 ports.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at this package?

ntfs-config - Enable/disable write support for any NTFS devices

But this one might be more what you are interested in

usbmount - automatically mount and unmount USB mass storage devices

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution over at the [Unix Stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25552/making-udev-ignore-certain-devices-during-boot), which might be applicable here. You need to create a new udev rules file, e.g. `/etc/udev/rules.d/90-hide-partitions.rules` and fill it with a rule matching your NTFS partition:

```
KERNEL=="sda2",ENV{UDISKS_PRESENTATION_HIDE}="1"
```

All of the above is taken from the linked solution. You need to adjust `sda2` with the name of your NTFS partition.